# ASP.NET Web API Controllers: Dependency injection via IOC Container vs Overloaded Constructors

Tags: asp.net-web-api, constructor, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have a controller that has a dependency on a service. I need to be able to pass in this service for unit test purposes, so I have the service passed in to the constructor.

My question is, what is the downside of having overloaded constructors like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    protected IStorageService StorageService;

    protected MyController()
    {
        StorageService = StorageServiceFactory.CreateStorageService(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    }

    protected MyController(IStorageService storageService)
    {
        StorageService = storageService;
    }
}
```

... where the unit test would call the second constructor and the normal use case would use the first constructor... versus getting rid of the first constructor and using an IOC container to inject the dependency?

In this particular case, because my concrete service requires User.Identity (which is specific to the request), this seems challenging to do from an IOC container. But there has to be a way people do it that way, and a reason for it, so I'd like to get some clarification.

Comment: Having multiple constructors is an anti-pattern. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) to understand why.

Comment: @Steven Thank you! This was the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with IocContainer simply because its more easy to use and you don't have to do something different for UnitTests. It will be more configurable and easy way to keep the implementation dependent on abstraction. Factory pattern is also useful (as StorageServiceFactory), but IocContainer will allow you to use latest mocking frameworks easily as well.

Code will look like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    protected IStorageService StorageService;

    protected MyController()
    {
        StorageService = StorageServiceFactory.CreateStorageService(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    }

    protected MyController(IStorageService storageService)
    {
        StorageService = storageService;
    }
}
```

IStorageService's implementation will look like this

```
public class StorageServiceImplementation : IStorageService
{
    public StorageServiceImplementation(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
    }
//IStorageService.Methods
}
```

This is how you can use structure map to create an instance of IStorageService and pass ClaimsIndentity as parameter

```
public static T ResolveInstanceWithCtorValue<T, I>(I ctorValue)
        {
            return ObjectFactory.Container.With(ctorValue).GetInstance<T>();
        }
```

And just resolve it like this:

```
IocContainer.ResolveInstance<IStorageService>(User.Identity);
```

Please let me know if there is more question.

Comment: Thank you! However User.Identity is not accessible from the place where IStorageService would be resolved. See my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947760/castle-windsor-di-installer-implementation-dependency-factory-method-requires